# Alternating row color for Listbox using MahApps.Metro

Tags: .net, wpf, listbox, mahapps.metro, alternating

I'm trying to create an alternating row color for my listbox in WPF while using the MahApps.Metro project.  When I add the style and triggers, the background of all items is still white:

```
        <Style TargetType="ListBox">
            <Setter Property="AlternationCount" Value="2" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Comment: Apply it on a ListBoxItem, not on a ListBox. And remember to set the AlternationCount on the ListBox.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the `Style` on the `ListBoxItem` instead of the `ListBox`, like this:

```
<ListBox AlternationCount="2">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

Don't forget to add the `AlternationCount` to the `ListBox`, as it is no longer being set in the `Style`